# Question on Hypothetico-Deductive Method

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mathematics, hume

I had another quiz related Hypothetico-Deductive (HD) Method. I couldn't answer this because the way it was posed is so baffling to me.

I am so sorry to ask all the basic questions (I think all these questions may come in the final exam, but for me it is still so much information).

So, which one is true?

1. HD is based on deduction rather than induction and, therefore, circumvents Hume's problem of induction.
2. HD is a scientific ideal that is rarely used in practice.
3. HD is a method for testing hypotheses.
4. HD uses both deduction and induction.

Comment: If your class is based on Popper, 1. is presumably correct, others might defend 4, 2. and 3. are widely off.

Comment: @Conifold From today's class, my professor said 4 is true... :S